# flow flow social stream not loading on first visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

not sure how to really ask this question so im just going to go ahed and hope somebody understands...

Ive recently installed "Flow Flow - Social Streaming plugin for wordpress"
https://codecanyon.net/item/flowflow-wordpress-social-stream-plugin/9319434/comments

I have a problem though...

When i load the page that contains the feed for the first time, it doesnt show.

Yet when i reload, the feed is there as it should be. Its really frustrating.

Wondered if anybody knew what the problem could be?

Also if it helps, on the first load of the page the javascript file for the plugin seems to not be pulled. However on reload its there.